# Sybase Worktable created for REFORMATTING - done normally (execution<1min), sometimes a table scan instead(8hrs), why?

Tags: sybase, optimization

Here is the problematic legacy code. #elig_patients has ~100k recs, no indexes. All tables grow very slowly. The problem (execution taking 7-8 hrs) started ovre a year ago very occasionally. It is now happening every 3rd or 4th night (runs on cron. There are no other jobs on the the server. I cannot reproduce this problem except very occasionally). Why does the optimizer decide NOT to create the worktable for #elig_patients when there is a problem?

```
    INSERT INTO #PatientData(patient_id, study_site_no, study_pat_id, mode)
    SELECT DISTINCT p.patient_id, s.study_site_no, p.study_pat_id, "sq"
      FROM study_site s, patient p, patient_visit pv, #elig_patients e
     WHERE s.site_id = p.site_id
       AND p.patient_id = pv.patient_id
       AND pv.patient_id = e.patient_id
       AND accept_status = 1
       AND image_status = 1
       AND label_status = 1
       AND ISNULL(sq_status,0) = 0
       AND ISNULL(review_flag,0) = 0
```

Here is the execution plan when things are proceeding smoothly

QUERY PLAN FOR STATEMENT 9 (at line 77).

```
STEP 1
    The type of query is INSERT.
    The update mode is direct.
    Worktable2 created for REFORMATTING.

    FROM TABLE
        study_site
        s
    Nested iteration.
    Table Scan.
    Forward scan.
    Positioning at start of table.
    Using I/O Size 2 Kbytes for data pages.
    With LRU Buffer Replacement Strategy for data pages.
    TO TABLE
        Worktable2.

STEP 2
    The type of query is INSERT.
    The update mode is direct.
    Worktable3 created for REFORMATTING.

    FROM TABLE
        #elig_patients
        e
    Nested iteration.
    Table Scan.
    Forward scan.
    Positioning at start of table.
    Using I/O Size 2 Kbytes for data pages.
    With LRU Buffer Replacement Strategy for data pages.
    TO TABLE
        Worktable3.

STEP 3
    The type of query is INSERT.
    The update mode is direct.
    Worktable1 created, in allpages locking mode, for DISTINCT.

    FROM TABLE
        patient
        p
    Nested iteration.
    Table Scan.
    Forward scan.
    Positioning at start of table.
    Using I/O Size 2 Kbytes for data pages.
    With LRU Buffer Replacement Strategy for data pages.

    FROM TABLE
        Worktable2.
    Nested iteration.
    Using Clustered Index.
    Forward scan.
    Positioning by key.
    Using I/O Size 2 Kbytes for data pages.
    With LRU Buffer Replacement Strategy for data pages.

    FROM TABLE
        patient_visit
        pv
    Nested iteration.
    Using Clustered Index.
    Index : pv_ind
    Forward scan.
    Positioning by key.
    Keys are:
        patient_id ASC
    Using I/O Size 2 Kbytes for data pages.
    With LRU Buffer Replacement Strategy for data pages.

    FROM TABLE
        Worktable3.
    EXISTS TABLE : nested iteration.
    Using Clustered Index.
    Forward scan.
    Positioning by key.
    Using I/O Size 2 Kbytes for data pages.
    With LRU Buffer Replacement Strategy for data pages.
    TO TABLE
        Worktable1.

STEP 4
    The type of query is INSERT.
    The update mode is direct.
    This step involves sorting.

    FROM TABLE
        Worktable1.
    Using GETSORTED
    Table Scan.
    Forward scan.
    Positioning at start of table.
    Using I/O Size 2 Kbytes for data pages.
    With MRU Buffer Replacement Strategy for data pages.
    TO TABLE
        #PatientData
    Using I/O Size 2 Kbytes for data pages.
```

Note that there are 4 steps. 
In Step 2: Worktable3 created for REFORMATTING. In Step 3 the Clustered Index on that table is used in the JOINs.

Here is the execution plan when the code executes for hours. Note there are 3 steps and the lack of use of a worktable for REFORMATTING the #elig_patients table.

QUERY PLAN FOR STATEMENT 9 (at line 77).

```
STEP 1
    The type of query is INSERT.
    The update mode is direct.
    Worktable2 created for REFORMATTING.

    FROM TABLE
        study_site
        s
    Nested iteration.
    Table Scan.
    Forward scan.
    Positioning at start of table.
    Using I/O Size 16 Kbytes for data pages.
    With LRU Buffer Replacement Strategy for data pages.
    TO TABLE
        Worktable2.

STEP 2
    The type of query is INSERT.
    The update mode is direct.
    Worktable1 created, in allpages locking mode, for DISTINCT.

    FROM TABLE
        #elig_patients
        e
    Nested iteration.
    Table Scan.
    Forward scan.
    Positioning at start of table.
    Using I/O Size 2 Kbytes for data pages.
    With LRU Buffer Replacement Strategy for data pages.

    FROM TABLE
        patient
        p
    Nested iteration.
    Table Scan.
    Forward scan.
    Positioning at start of table.
    Using I/O Size 16 Kbytes for data pages.
    With LRU Buffer Replacement Strategy for data pages.

    FROM TABLE
        Worktable2.
    Nested iteration.
    Using Clustered Index.
    Forward scan.
    Positioning by key.
    Using I/O Size 16 Kbytes for data pages.
    With LRU Buffer Replacement Strategy for data pages.

    FROM TABLE
        patient_visit
        pv
    EXISTS TABLE : nested iteration.
    Using Clustered Index.
    Index : pv_ind
    Forward scan.
    Positioning by key.
    Keys are:
        patient_id ASC
    Using I/O Size 16 Kbytes for data pages.
    With LRU Buffer Replacement Strategy for data pages.
    TO TABLE
        Worktable1.

STEP 3
    The type of query is INSERT.
    The update mode is direct.
    This step involves sorting.

    FROM TABLE
        Worktable1.
    Using GETSORTED
    Table Scan.
    Forward scan.
    Positioning at start of table.
    Using I/O Size 16 Kbytes for data pages.
    With MRU Buffer Replacement Strategy for data pages.
    TO TABLE
        #PatientData
    Using I/O Size 2 Kbytes for data pages.
```

The command completed with no results returned

Answer (score 0):

sounds like #elig_patients is a small number of records compared with the permanent tables, so what you want is to table scan it with index joins for all the others.

For that you need indexes on patient Id on the 2 patient tables and site_id on the site table.

You wouldn't have reformats and/or tablescans if those existed I don't think.

Changing query plans is probably statistics being out of date.

Do you REORG the tables periodically, and do  you update statistics?  If this is Sybase 15 then UPDATE INDEX STATISTICS is better (see docs, see also DATACHANGE if you need to economise.)

Comment: Thanks @Abe for your input. It is Sybase 12.5.1. The relative sizes of tables: 
#elig_patients ~100k
#patient ~ 37k
#study_site ~ 500
#patient_visit ~110k

Comment: Several indexes are in place, including those you mention. The statistics are updated. We do update statistics regularly on these tables, and as mentioned they are all very slow growing. I will ask our DBA about REORG, I was not familiar with this operation. 

I was able to stop the problem by redesigning the procedure and removing an unnecessary column from the #elig_patients table thus bringing its size down to ~37k recs, and adding a non-clustered index on patient_id.

Comment: Is this inside a stored procedure, or is it embedded in perl,shell,whatever?  The reason I ask is to know whether elig_patients is populated when the statement is compiled.  If not that might be a reason.  If all these joins are indexed you shouldn't have a problem, and I'd half expect it to be to do with #elig_patients not having stats at the point the statement is compiled, either because it's all in an SP, or else if embedded, the populatio of the temp tab is in the same sql batch as the statement that's problematic.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks again for your input. This is inside a stored procedure. The table is created and dropped in the proc.